# How to get a Jquery object of a specific class which has a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get a Jquery object of a specific class which has a specific value.

For example, I have these input tags with the class name "track-interval".

```
<input type="radio" class="track-interval" value="1" name="interval" />
<input type="radio" class="track-interval" value="5" name="interval" />
```

The first one has a value "1" and the second one has a value "5".
Actually, in the real code that I'm working on, I have more input tags that have the same class name.

Now, I'd like to get a Jquery object of a input tag whose class name is "track-interval" and whose value is "5".

```
var trackInterval = $(".track-interval);
```

I know how to get a Jquery object whose class name is "track-interval".

But, I don't know how to get a Jquery object whose class name is "track-interval" and also whose value is "5".

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var trackInterval = $(".track-interval[value=5]");
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/96QTA/)**

Comment: By the way, is it possible to get the same result by using the Jquery object which I put into the variable "trackInterval"??

something like trackInterval.find([value=5].

Comment: @crzyonez777, if you can use `trackInterval` later? yes, its in cache, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/96QTA/2/